# ¿Cómo se nombran los *cul-de-sac* en diferentes países?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, españa, hispanoamérica, español-neutral

Hoy dando vueltas por internet, encontré la expresión *cul-de-sac* que puede traducirse como calle sin salida, lo que en el habla cotidiana en Colombia se conoce como '[Calle ciega](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=calle)' (El diccionario de americanismos lo reconoce solo en Venezuela, pero no vengo a discutir con la academia) o '[Calle mocha](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Jy6gkMm63Y)' (este  último no avalado por el DAMER).

En México, Honduras y Uruguay aparece como 'Calle cerrada', en República Dominicana como 'Calle de bolsillo', y desde el DLE '[Callejón](https://dle.rae.es/callej%C3%B3n?m=form)' aplica para Cuba.

El término 'Callejón sin salida' o 'punto muerto' aparecen en Wikipedia, pero quisiera saber si la frase inicial (Calle sin salida) sería la óptima a un nivel de 'español neutral' y qué otros términos existen en los diferentes dialectos para referirse a estas calles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Cul-de-sac* en inglés es un cultismo que viene del francés y se usa especialmente en su uso abstracto de *punto muerto* que menciona la Wikipedia. Su uso literal varía según países. En España, por ejemplo, usamos *callejón sin salida*.

Detallo aquí los usos de la expresión *cul-de-sac* según países, a partir de lo que indicaste y ampliando un poco:

#### Colombia

- [Calle ciega](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=calle)
- [Calle mocha](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Jy6gkMm63Y)

#### Cuba

- [Callejón](https://dle.rae.es/callej%C3%B3n?m=form)

#### España

- Callejón sin salida

#### Honduras

- Calle cerrada

#### México

- Calle cerrada

#### República Dominicana

- Calle de bolsillo

#### Uruguay

- Calle cerrada

#### Venezuela

- Calle ciega

Animaos a editar y mejorar la lista con las otras que conozcáis.

Comment: En frances es impasse o sans issue pero no cul-de-sac. Curioso.

Comment: @mdewey recuerdo leer lo de _cul-de-sac_ en un libreto en inglés de un disco de jazz. Me llamó la atención su uso

Comment: En catalán es "atzucac", palabra preciosa.

Answer (score 3):

En España, a nivel ingeniería/obra civil y en el ámbito ferroviario se utiliza también "fondo de saco":
http://diccionario.raing.es/es/lema/fondo-de-saco-0

Sin embargo no es común en el habla cotidiana.

Answer (score 0):

En Reino Unido cul de sac se usa para indicar que la calle es tranquila, puramente residencial, generalmente no tiene salida, pero las hay que la tienen. Dicho esto, callejón es una calle pequeña y oscura, no tiene por qué ser cul de sac, ejemplo de callejón: en los barrios de casas residenciales en Reino Unido, la vía trasera, por donde pasa el camión de la basura que en muchos casos no tiene ni nombre.

Equivalente en español, no creo que haya ninguna expresión que se ajuste al 100%. Sin embargo, yo lo traduciría como zona/calle residencial, aunque no es exactamente eso.

Comment: Can you give a source to back that up as in the dialect I speak (south east England) it would always be a no through road.

Comment: https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/property-86780531.html, check the map and you will see that the listed property is cul de sac according to description but the street do not meet what you are saying

Comment: The road comes to a dead end. There is what appears to be a pedestrian access beyond that but it is still a dead-end.

Comment: I certainly agree it has that connotation, probably due to its use in advertising or its "fancy" (French) sound, but I doubt most people would use it to describe anything but a closed street, usually residential with a traffic circle at the end. Without a circle to turn around, I think "dead end" would be more common. I could imagine that some people would use cul-de-sac for the area around a residential traffic circle even if it has an exit, but at least in the United States that is not a common setup.